# Why does my 2 bulb fixture have 40 volts going to it when a bulb is removed?

Tags: electrical

When second bulb is removed in the fixture in the off position, the remaining bulb lights dim (fixture switch still off) and the socket that is bulb less reads 40 volts, when replacing the bulb both lights go off. 3way seems to work fine with 2 bulbs in. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So you have a two bulb fixture with independent switches?

Comment: @Chief Two Pencils   yes, the fixture is on a 3way system fed and legged at the top off the stairs, I was wondering if it could be caused by a pinched wire or maybe a problem with the neutral

Answer (score 2):

Any time I see a strange voltage like 40 volts, I immediately suspect a broken wire or a bad terminal. Since installing and removing one of the bulbs seems to cause a problem, I would start by removing that fixture and inspecting it and the nearby wiring for faults.

Comment: Will start with replacing the fixture and go from there, tracing wires in a 2 story modular is a nightmare. Thank you longneck for your input.

Comment: The most likely place for a broken wire is where the sheath is stripped back. And the only place that the sheath should be stripped is in a box. I don't think you will need to trace wires to find this problem.